# Update a specific object value under YAML based on a condition using yq

Tags: yq

Using https://github.com/mikefarah/yq v4

Given a `sample.yaml` file like this:

```
spec:
  chart:
    name: my-chart
    version: 0.0.1
---
spec:
  chart:
    name: something-else
    version: 0.0.2
```

I want to update the `version` value but only for the instance of `.spec.chart.version` where the sibling `.spec.chart.name` element == `my-chart`.  The result would need to output the entire yaml file so that I can edit the YAML file inline.

If I use a select like

```
yq e -i 'select(.spec.chart.name == "my-chart") | .spec.chart.version = "1.0.0"' sample.yaml
```

The second instance of `.spec` has been removed:

```
spec:
  chart:
    name: my-chart
    version: 1.0.0
```

Any advice?

Comment: The idea is right, but you need to use the [Update assignment operator](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/comment-operators#use-update-assign-to-perform-relative-updates) `|=` to perform the update on the selected object, i.e. `yq e 'select(.spec.chart.name == "my-chart").spec.chart.version |= "1.0.0"' yaml`

Comment: The above suggestion does not work. The problem is that `select` is a filter. If the chart name doesn't match, the node is dropped. What we really need here is a conditional update (not a filter).

Answer (score 20):

```
yq '(.spec.chart | select(.name == "my-chart") | .version) = "1.0"' file.yaml
```

Explanation:

- First we want to find all the (potential) nodes we want to update, in this case, it's `.spec.chart`.
- Next we filter out those node to be only the ones we're interested in, `select(.name == "my-chart")`
- Now we select the field we want to update `.version`
- Importantly, the whole LHS is in brackets, so those matching `version` nodes are passed to the update (=) function.  If you don't do this, then the filter happens before (and separately to) the update - and so you only see filtered results.

Disclaimer: I wrote yq

Comment: I had a similar problem, and this solution resolved it. Thank you!

Comment: @mike.f how can I update `yq '(.spec.chart.version) = "1.0"' file.yaml` for first or some n-th document in yaml file ?

Comment: hmm.. got it.. `yq '(select(documentIndex == 1) | .spec.chart.version) = "1.0"' file.yaml` thanks for the yq ..

Comment: @mike.f how can I update the version to be dependent on another value in that `spec` and not hardcoded value? I tried something like this `yq '(select(documentIndex == 1) | .spec.chart.version) = .spec.otherproperty file.yaml` but it always grabs the value of the last .spec.otherproperty

Comment: @Rafi, in that case I'd use a `with` block (see https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/with) and do :`yq 'with(.spec.chart | select(.name == "my-chart");  .version = .other)'`

Comment: Awesome @mike.f! Thank you so much! I spent several hours trying to figure out how to see all results instead of filtered ones. Hope this could be explained better in the docs.